# Help on Algebraic Side Channel Attacks

Tags: cryptanalysis, post-quantum-cryptography, side-channel-attack, algebraic-attack

I am a master student in computer security, I am preparing a dissertation thesis in the theme is: Algebraic cryptanalys by auxiliary channels, I need reference on this theme (book, thesis, ...), and even I'm looking for specialists in the subject to contact them and work together.
  thank you for your attention.

Comment: [Algebraic Cryptanalysis](https://www.amazon.com/Algebraic-Cryptanalysis-Gregory-Bard-ebook/dp/B00FB36BZO) by Gregory V. Bard/

Comment: What do you mean with "auxiliary channels"? Algebraic Side-Channel Attacks like in https://ia.cr/2009/279 ?

Comment: Hu , yes i mean Side-Channel Attacks , my study is the algebraic cryptanalys when i use Side-Channel Attacks l

Comment: i mean algebraic side-chanel attack